# Damped harmonic oscillator with different initial amplitudes

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

If a string under tension is plucked, and that string goes into underdamped harmonic oscillations, the graph of the exponential decay of the amplitude looks something like this:

[image]

If I were to pluck that string so that the initial amplitude is much less, would the trend of exponential decay of energy look the same, or would it look like the point on the previous graph where the amplitude is equal to the initial amplitude of the second oscillator, onwards? This would look something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: you could mathematically model the amplitude with $A=A_0e^{-bt/2m}$, though an answer explaining the physical intuition behind the solution would be helpful too.

Comment: Yeah, so if the exponential term is dependent on only time, then the trend should be the same, but I don't understand the physical intuition.

Comment: It takes the same amount of time for the amplitude to change by some proportional amount (e.g to reduce by half, or whatever) independent of when you start measuring from or what the initial amplitude is, That is one of the basic properties of exponential grpwth and decay.

Comment: So that would mean the trend of exponential decay would always remain the same, regardless of the initial amplitude, right?

Comment: Yes the trend of exponential decay will remain the same because $b$(the decay constant) is independent of the initial amplitude.

Comment: But your graph will flatten out because the newer amplitude will be smaller.

Comment: But if you were to zoom in on the y-axis scale, it would look the same (not flattened)?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that technically the exponential just describes a sort of "envelope" for the oscillation. It is not actually the amplitude.

Comment: Yes, but can't the decay amplitudes can be modelled to a certain extent by the exponential?

Comment: @JackCeroni Yeah, it's not a huge difference. It's just that the maxima/minima of the oscillations aren't tangent to the exponential envelope. But your question seems to be more about the behavior of exponential decay, so I think it is mostly irrelevant.